# Possible HTTP Request states after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, http

I'm trying to submit a form and get the results inpage using AJAX. I call a JS function onsubmit which makes the AJAX call, and includes this code:

```
        request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        /* set up request here */
        request.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            /* do what I need */
            alert('Success');
        } else {
            /* do what I need */
            alert('Failed');
        }
    }
```

However, the Failed alert shows up multiple times (3 at least) before the Success one, so I guess I'm getting many different statuses before the successful one? How can I check which ones I get, and what to expect when the submission is failed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request goes through four phases. The readyStates. Every time the readystate updates it fires the event. `0` indicates a failure and `4` indicates that the request has finished. the `status` returns the http code. `200` indicates success. There was an answer and it returned a *request body*. All other codes indicate there was something wrong on the server side. Eg. 404, 403, or 500. You can safely ignore the other `readystates`. But catch any status other than 200 as failure.

Comment: Do I still get 200 status if the server side form validation fails, and it returns the form with error messages?

Comment: Yes, a 200 only means that the request returned a valid response. Except when the form validation (read: server side script) returns a different header. My php script returns a 403 header when somebody attempts to access a page restricted by permissions.

Comment: So, to find out if the validation was failed, I need to change header in the server script (I'm using Zend Form), or is there any other way to find it out from my JS?

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying. Zend returns HTML isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if, in case of unsuccessful validation, it changes the header already. I need to show the Success alert only if the form passed the server side validation, so checking the 200 status would not be enough if I still get that when validation fails.

Comment: What does Zend returns when the form validation is not valid?

Comment: It returns the populated form with relative validation error messages.

Comment: Well that's a nice response. You could use jQuery or plain JavaScript to replace the form on your page with the validated one.

Comment: Yes, I do that already. The only thing to solve is how to just send the Success alert if the form passes validation. I think I can easily solve that by adding some other condition tied to the return of message errors from Zend, but was just wondering if I could simply find that out from the response itself.

Answer (score 1):

You only ever get one status, but you get [multiple states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties).

Check to see if the `readyState` is `4` or `0` (since either of those states indicate that there is no more of the response to wait for).

Then throw an error if it is `0` or test the `status` if it is `4`.

If the `readyState` is any other value, then ignore it (unless you want to do stuff in other states).